# Get orders from 12 hours ago SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I'm trying to pull records from a SQL Server database where the `OrderDate` (`datetime`) was 12 hours ago. Ideally I'd like to do the whole hour.. for instance..

If I run the query now, at 21.38 (my time) the query would pull records that have the `datetime` of  9.00 - 10.00 I'm not bothered about the actual date as such, just orders from 12 hours ago.. this query will run every hour, so the next time it ran it would run at 22.38 and would pull orders from 10.00 - 11.00..

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.[Order].OrderID, 
    dbo.Customer.Forename, 
    dbo.Customer.Surname, 
    dbo.Customer.Email, 
    dbo.[Order].OrderDate, 
    dbo.[Order].OrderStatusID, 
    dbo.[Order].WebsiteID, 
    dbo.Addresses.CountryID
FROM dbo.[Order] 
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer 
    ON dbo.[Order].CustomerID = dbo.Customer.CustomerID
INNER JOIN dbo.Addresses 
    ON dbo.[Order].BillingAddressID = dbo.Addresses.AddressID 
    AND dbo.[Order].DeliveryAddressID = dbo.Addresses.AddressID
    AND dbo.Customer.CustomerID = dbo.Addresses.CustomerID
WHERE (dbo.[Order].WebsiteID IN (1, 2, 8, 12)) 
  AND (dbo.[Order].OrderStatusID = 1) 
  AND (dbo.[Order].OrderDate >= DATEADD(hour, - 12, GETDATE())) 
  AND (dbo.[Order].OrderDate <= DATEADD(hour, - 11, GETDATE()))
```

Update:

This is the correct query I'm currently trying

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.[Order].OrderID, dbo.Customer.Forename,     dbo.Customer.Surname, dbo.Customer.Email, dbo.[Order].OrderDate,     dbo.[Order].OrderStatusID, dbo.[Order].WebsiteID, 
                       dbo.Addresses.CountryID
FROM         dbo.[Order] INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Customer ON dbo.[Order].CustomerID = dbo.Customer.CustomerID     LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Addresses ON dbo.[Order].DeliveryAddressID =     dbo.Addresses.AddressID AND dbo.Customer.CustomerID = dbo.Addresses.CustomerID
WHERE     (dbo.[Order].WebsiteID IN (1, 2, 8, 12)) AND (dbo.[Order].OrderStatusID = 1)     AND (dbo.[Order].OrderDate >= DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0))     AND 
                      (dbo.[Order].OrderDate < DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0,     GETDATE()) - 11, 0))
```

Comment: Do you have a program to run this sql-code? (Then this would be much easier to accomplish)

Comment: How sure are you that the query will run every hour? What I mean by this is, what would happen if you missed an hour, perhaps due to server restart due to windows updates, power outage, whatnot? I would instead try to make sure you process every order up to and including that hour, that hasn't already been processed.

Comment: Hi, Yes the query runs via a WinForms app, using c# every hour..

Comment: Also, thanks @Sachin - I was just editing it to try and fix.. thanks!

Comment: I think what Lasse Karlsen is suggesting is that while it should run every hour, what if it doesn't?  Even banks have occasional glitches where processes miss a run.  Is it a problem if the 10:00-11:00 hour was not processed yet?

Comment: Especially since he says "winforms" application, which suggests that the machine has to be at least logged in for the application to run.

Comment: Yes, to both.. it's not a major issue if its missed - it's only sending an email to someone - thanks..

Comment: Do you realize that your statement will filter out results where the BillingAddressID and DeliveryAddressID are not equal?

Comment: If you have C# code, I suggest you write a query with standard time window (BETWEEN), with dates calculated at runtime and passed as parameters to the query. That should save you from some headache.

Comment: @Neolisk, I think that only saves headaches if you're more comfortable writing C# code.  ;)

Comment: @tommy_o: Also if you later decide to move to another DB engine, which happened to me. I am not sure how Oracle will handle this type of constructs: `DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, GetDate())-12, 0)`. :)

Comment: @Neolisk, that unnecessarily changes the scope of the question by saying the OP might have to later tackle changing to a new DB engine.  And that may be the least of her/his problems at that point :)  Most places I've worked write their SQL code into sprocs with params for this problem (so at least the application should, in theory, be able to call the sproc with parameters the same way no matter what RDB they're calling -- then just fix the SQL within the sproc to be DB-specific).

Comment: @tommy_o: In my world you avoid SPs at all costs. Depending on the amount of business logic you need to maintain, you effort may increase substantially. If you only have a few developers to care about everything, you can understand me. OOP brings effort down to the minimum. You don't have OOP in SQL. We do all such date calculations in code, both for reporting purposes (SSRS) and regular windows (and web) applications. I don't mean to argue, just saying there can be different situations, depending on the environment.

Comment: Yes, we're saying almost the same thing -- business logic outside of SQL code, but we often use stored procedures (so select, update, insert, delete sprocs for changes).  That way, all points of contact between the middle-tier and DB are the same, no matter what is calling.  Then, if there's a bug, the SQL code is decoupled from the middle-tier (excluding parameters).  But it all depends on the scenario, of course (like you said).  SO just warned me about extended discssions :o  Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this where clause instead

```
WHERE   dbo.[Order].WebsiteID IN (1, 2, 8, 12) 
        AND dbo.[Order].OrderStatusID = 1 
        AND OrderDate >=  DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, GetDate())-12, 0)
        AND OrderDate <   DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, GetDate())-11, 0)
```

Comment: This yields no results from my database, and based on my criteria there where 6 orders between 9-10am..

Comment: @MichaelEaton well what time is it now (we have no idea what time zone you're in)? What does `SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0);` yield?

Comment: Aaron: Right now its 22:15 your query produces this: 2013-05-17 10:00:00.000

Comment: @MichaelEaton, turn the inner join on `dbo.Addresses` into a left join and see if the resultset is different.  You're only retrieving records where BillingAddressID = DeliveryAddressID (and I apologize if that is intentional).

Comment: Nope.. still no results.. as the time has now moved on, it should pull orders made between 10-11am - which manually looking through the database should be 3 results.. Mike

Comment: try (temporarily) removing the other where clause criteria to see if you return any rows.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (and I cleaned up your whitespace a bit):

```
declare @topofhour datetime
SELECT @topofhour = dateadd(hour,-11,dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,0,getdate()),0))

--checking against the provided scenario, since i've buggered this up twice
--
--declare @topofhour  datetime 
--select @topofhour  = '05/17/2013 21:38:00'
--select @topofhour  = dateadd(hour,-11,dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,0,@topofhour ),0))
--select dateadd(hour,-1,@topofhour), @topofhour
--
-- -- results are `2013-05-17 09:00:00.000,2013-05-17 10:00:00.000`

SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.[Order].OrderID
            , dbo.Customer.Forename
            , dbo.Customer.Surname
            , dbo.Customer.Email
            , dbo.[Order].OrderDate
            , dbo.[Order].OrderStatusID
            , dbo.[Order].WebsiteID
            , dbo.Addresses.CountryID 
FROM         dbo.[Order] 
INNER JOIN  dbo.Customer 
ON          dbo.[Order].CustomerID = dbo.Customer.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN  dbo.Addresses
AND         dbo.[Order].DeliveryAddressID = deliveryAddress.AddressID 
AND         dbo.Customer.CustomerID = deliveryAddress.CustomerID
WHERE       (dbo.[Order].WebsiteID IN (1, 2, 8, 12)) 
AND         (dbo.[Order].OrderStatusID = 1) 
AND         (dbo.[Order].OrderDate between dateadd(hour,-1,@topofhour) and @topofhour)
```

**UPDATE:**
I redid this.  Please try running this instead.  If it returns what you expect, then add the other WHERE lines back.

```
DECLARE     @topDate datetime, @bottomDate datetime

SELECT      @topDate        = DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0)
            ,@bottomDate    = DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, GETDATE()) - 11, 0)

SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT o.OrderID
            , c.Forename
            , c.Surname
            , c.Email
            , o.OrderDate
            , o.OrderStatusID
            , o.WebsiteID
            , a.CountryID
FROM        dbo.[Order] as o
left join   dbo.Customer as c
ON          o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID     
left join   dbo.Addresses as a
ON          o.DeliveryAddressID = a.AddressID 
AND         c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
WHERE       (o.OrderDate BETWEEN @bottomDate AND @topDate)
--AND         (o.WebsiteID IN (1, 2, 8, 12)) 
--AND         (o.OrderStatusID = 1)
```

Comment: BETWEEN is inclusive, so if you said 'WHERE [field] IS BETWEEN 1 and 10', it would return true for every integer between 1 and 10, including 1 and 10 (the same as WHERE [field] >= 1 AND [field] <= 10)

Comment: The variable `@topofhour` actually seems to be midnight of the day.

Comment: Still looks like you are missing the "12 hours ago" criteria.

Comment: I added a second inner join, splitting the address table into aliased `billingAddress` and `deliveryAddress`.  Otherwise, the select statement only returns records where dbo.Order has DeliveryAddressID = BillingAddressID.  Code assumes that DeliveryAddressID and BillingAddressID are `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Updated again to only return based on DeliveryAddressID

Comment: I've just tried it again, (fixing a few little mistakes..) but still no results - Mike

Comment: Can you add a record that you're trying to capture?  Right-click, copy with headers?  It might be tough to make that legible.

Comment: `ORDERID` `ORDERDATE`
`87639` `2013-05-17 10:52:11.000`
`87640` `2013-05-17 10:53:46.000`
`87641` `2013-05-17 10:55:48.000`
`87642` `2013-05-17 11:07:24.000`

Comment: And whats the output of `SELECT      getdate(), DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0), DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, GETDATE()) - 11, 0)` ?